# NPAPI load third-party DLL

Tags: npapi

I am developing an NPAPI Firefox plugin and I have a question.

I need to load a third-party DLL (such as D:\mydll.dll), but on some computers mydll.dll is not in the system path or in c:\windows\system32 and I get loading errors.

Here is the code:

```
SetCurrentDirectory ("d:\");
m_hModule = LoadLibrary ("mydll.dll");
```

LoadLibrary returns 126. I checked with DEPENDS.EXE to view the dependent modules and everything looks fine. I do not know what the problem is.

Another problem is that I want the plug-in to work in Safari (my safari is version 5.17).  I copy it into Safari's Plugins directory and it tells me it cannot find the plug-in. I want to know how to solve this.

Thank you, and please excuse my poor English.

Comment: I still can not understand why can not load third-party DLL, why the same DLL can be loaded in the system path

Comment: First of all, I recommend that you only ask one question at a time; these are two completely different questions.

Answer (score 2):

Setting the current directory will not always work when in a plugin because you don't own the process.  The command that you want is [SetDllDirectory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686203%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

```
SetDllDirectory("D:\");
m_hModule = LoadLibrary("mydll.dll");
```

Of course, I don't recommend that you ever assume a DLL is in the root of the drive =] What I would do is put the DLL you need in the same directory as the plugin DLL and then you can get the path of the DLL using [GetModuleFilename](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683197%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

For installing, rather than putting the plugin in the plugins/ directory in the firefox (or safari) directory you should [install it through the windows registry](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Gecko_Plugin_API_Reference/Plug-in_Development_Overview#Windows_Installation_Using_the_Registry). This will make it visible for firefox, chrome, and safari.

You may want to consider using [FireBreath](http://firebreath.org) instead of implementing the NPAPI interfaces yourself; it takes care of most of the tricky parts and leaves you free to focus on the important parts of your plugin.

Comment: I used SetEnvironmentVariable to solve the problem of third-party DLL.thank you

Comment: SetDllDirectory is far less likely to cause you issues, but I suppose whatever works.